# PHP shell_exec command between two numbers

Tags: php, shell, shell-exec

I have this list of files and I need to get the files between two dates like this command shell in PHP:

> ```
> all_doc_test_2017-07-01.dog
> all_doc_test_2017-07-02.dog
> all_doc_test_2017-07-03.dog
> all_doc_test_2017-07-04.dog
> all_doc_test_2017-07-05.dog
> all_doc_test_2017-07-06.dog
> all_doc_test_2017-07-07.dog
> all_doc_test_2017-07-08.dog
> all2_doc_test_2017-07-07.dog
> all3_doc_test_2017-07-07.dog
> all4_doc_test_2017-07-07.dog
> ```

I use this command to get one date:

```
shell_exec("ls -d /home/doc/*07.dog ");
```

so I get like this :

> ```
> all_doc_test_2017-07-07.dog
> all2_doc_test_2017-07-07.dog
> all3_doc_test_2017-07-07.dog
> all4_doc_test_2017-07-07.dog
> ```

I need a command to get the files between two numbers like this:

```
ls -d /home/doc/*01.dog  && ls -d /home/doc/*06.dog
```

and get this:

> ```
> all_doc_test_2017-07-01.dog
> all_doc_test_2017-07-02.dog
> all_doc_test_2017-07-03.dog
> all_doc_test_2017-07-04.dog
> all_doc_test_2017-07-05.dog
> all_doc_test_2017-07-06.dog
> ```

Comment: take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: You don't need to use `shell_exec()` and it seems it doesn't help you very much. Use [`FileSystemIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.filesystemiterator.php) to enumerate the files in the directory then check their names and keep only those that match your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP's glob() could handle that:

```
$files = glob('./path/*07-0[1-6].dog');
```

Comment: Thank you very much it's work for me like this
shell_exec("ls -d /home/dov/*0[5-7].dog");
Thanks

Comment: but why the route through shell_exec()? glob() implements the same syntax